# Transition with js to a constantly moving element

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have a cart logo on a header with sticky position and i have some cards in the website, when i click on a card a small logo flies from the clicked card to the cart logo then disappears, i'm using JS to get the absolute position of the cart logo then adding a top/left to my little small logo that i want to reach the cart.
everything is working fine until the user scroll right after clicking on the card then the logo misses the cart cause its position have moved.
how can i solve this?
if this has any value my transition duration is 2 seconds

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on how to write posts that best enable the community to provide helpful guidance.  With no code and a somewhat vague description this is nearly impossible to answer as it is currently written.  I would recommend including code in the body of the question as a [mcve] snippet, and write the steps to reproduce the issue, the expected behavior, and the actual behavior.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.